# Combine First and Last name into single field in RubyonRails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have only one field in database "User_Name", I need to persist the combination of first and last name into that field.
I am getting issue in this line **<%= f.text_field(:firstName, params[:firstName]) %>** because i don't any firstName column in my model. 
Help me out regarding this.

```
    <%= form_for(@user,url: "/user", :method => :post) do |f| %>

<%= f.label("First Name") %>
<%= f.text_field(:firstName, params[:firstName]) %></br>
<%= f.label("Last Name") %>
<%= f.text_field(:lastName, params[:lastName]) %></br>
<%= f.label("Email Address") %>
<%= f.text_field(:email, params[:email]) %></br>

<%= f.label("Password") %>
<%= f.password_field(:password, params[:password]) %></br>

<%= f.label("Confirm Password") %>
<%= f.password_field(:confirmPassword, params[:confirmPassword]) %></br>
<%= f.label("College") %>
<%= f.text_field(:college, params[:college]) %></br>
<%= f.label("Major") %>
<%= f.text_field(:major, params[:major]) %></br>

<%= f.label("Current Job") %>
<%= f.text_field(:currentJob, params[:currentJob]) %></br>
<%= f.submit("Register",class: "btn btn-primary") %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show `first_name` and `last_name` in the form and store `full_name` only in the DB, you can do following changes in your model:

```
attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name

before_validation :set_full_name

def first_name
  full_name.split(' ')[0]
end

def last_name
  full_name.split(' ')[1]
end

def set_full_name
  self.full_name = [first_name, last_name].join(' ')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have that field in the DB why are you using it in your `form`?

Your options are:

1) Change the DB to first and last name

2) Change your form to 1 field

3) create the methods `firstName=` and `firstName` (in RoR you usually use with "_", i.e. `first_name`

Option 3 not tested, but should work (you need to split your db field etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Forms using the model in Rails should reflect what data you want to encapsulate in the model directly, to reduce the likelihood that you or someone else gets mixed up on what the model *actually* receives from this form.

To that end, I would recommend you do away with the `firstName` and `lastName` fields, and instead go with `:user_name`.  The UX should explain that it should be both their first and last name (or some other name if they want).  This keeps your form and your data models consistent with one another.